# What does mov from hex[eax] mean?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I'm trying to reverse engineering a simple program (learning purpose) using IDA and I got stuck on this instruction:

```
mov    dl, byte_404580[eax]
```

This instruction stores in the first 8 bit of `EDX` a value derived from `EAX` and `byte_404580` but I don't know how it is actually computed.

Looking at `byte_404580` is stored the hex value `69h`:

```
.data:00404580 byte_404580     db 69h
```

Is it the same of `[eax+69h]` or not?

Comment: No, It is similar to array notation.The instruction fetches the byte at an offset of `eax` from  `byte_404580`

Comment: Also check *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148010/understanding-x86-mov-syntax)*

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Good answer, please fill an answer instead of a comment next time so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: It's using 00404580+(contents of eax) as the source address (I suppose you're using ATT syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copying the comments of Extreme Coders so the question can be marked as answered.)

It is similar to array notation.The instruction fetches the byte at an offset of `eax` from `byte_404580`.

Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148010/understanding-x86-mov-syntax